# Delphi: save a folder with files using Synopse Big Table

Tags: delphi, file, backup, save, bigtable

How can I save a whole folder with it's files and folders using Synopse Big Table? I need to make a backup of my files without compression. I heard that Synopse Big Table is good for this purpose. But I couldn't find info to accomplish that.

Thanks!

Comment: Why without compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you write this question [in the library forum](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=2569)?

OK, here is some sample code:

```
function SaveFolderToBigTableFile(const aFolder, aFile: TFileName): boolean;
var SR: TSearchRec;
    BT: TSynBigTableString;
    aPath: TFileName;
    Path: RawUTF8;
begin
  DeleteFile(aFile);
  result := true;
  BT := TSynBigTableString.Create(aFile);
  try
    aPath := ExtractFilePath(aFolder);
    Path := StringToUTF8(aPath);
    if FindFirst(aPath+'*.*',faAnyFile,SR)=0 then
    try
      repeat
        if (SR.Name[1]='.') or (faDirectory and SR.Attr<>0) then
          Continue;
        if BT.Add(StringFromFile(aPath+SR.Name),StringToUTF8(SR.Name))<>0 then
          writeln(SR.Name,' added') else begin
          result := false;
          writeln(SR.Name,' ERROR');
        end;
        if BT.CurrentInMemoryDataSize>100000000 then
          BT.UpdateToFile;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
    finally
      FindClose(SR);
    end;
  finally
    BT.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The trick is to use a `TSynBigTableString` class using the file name as key.

You can add very fast compression just by using our SynLZ library (much faster than zip, but of course with a bit less compression ratio).